# Pine Script - Strategy analysis only within a specific time of day each already designated trading days

Tags: pine-script

I want to 'turn off' the strategy during after mkt sessions or simply to be active only during periods of US mkt hours.  But i dont want my strategy to consider data outside that period.  is that possible?

this is my code to constrain my trading conditions but it does not constrain the analysis.

```
TradingSession = input.session(title="Trading Session", defval="0635-1320", tooltip="time period for active trading")
TradingSessionShaded = input.bool(title="Shade Trading Session?", defval=true, tooltip="Change the background color based on whether the current bar falls within the trading session?")
inSession(trade) => na(time(timeframe.period, trade + ":23456", "America/Los_Angeles")) == false and time >= timestamp("01 Jan 2021 13:30 +0000") and time <= timestamp("1 Jan 2099 19:30 +0000")
cantrade = inSession(TradingSession)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use two variables for the session hours and days you want to trade. Then use the `time` function to see if you are within this time window.

Here is an example that works between 08:00-22:00 and Mon-Fri:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script", overlay=true)

timeAllowed = input.session("0800-2200", "Allowed hours")
daysAllowed = input.string("12345")

timeIsAllowed = time(timeframe.period, timeAllowed + ":" + daysAllowed)

plot(series=timeIsAllowed ? low : na, color=color.green, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_circles)
```

Please see where the green dots are:
[image]

If you for example, don't want to update some calculations when you are out of this time window, use `timeIsAllowed` as a condition for your calculations.

Comment: thank you. will give it go!  appreciate the prompt reply!!

Comment: No problem. Let me know if you run into any issues.

Comment: i have separate question if you dont mind.  I have a cross over indicator to say buy on a cross over and gets out the earlier of (i) take profit or (ii) cross over. 
 However, if i take profit i remain in the 'buy' indicator position so it wants to buy again.  What i want is not buy again until a cross over has occurred between the last take profit and a cross over.  can you think of easy way to code this?

Comment: Please ask a new question for that.